# Python mqtt stops publishing

Tags: python-3.x, mqtt, paho

This simple code stops publishing to the broker after 20/30 messages. The print(frame) statement continues to work, but no frame is published on the topic:

```
client = mqtt.Client("myMonitor")
client.connect(broker)

try:
    while 1:
        # Read data from BUS
        frame = RecData(smon)
        if frame.count("##") >= 1:
           print(frame)
           client.publish("salty/monitor",frame)
except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print("KeyB Interrupt")
        ExitApp()
```

Where do I am wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't started the client loop, so any message bigger than a single TCP packet will lock up the client.

You need to add `client.loop_start()` before the loop